# Require one parameter with one switch and two with another

Tags: powershell

I have the following parameter definition. In this script, I must have the user's access id, access key, and account name. I must also have either a device id, device name, or disply name. Finally, I require the inclusion of one or more property names and the associated value(s).

The script uses this information to add the property name and value to the device (in our monitoring system). Now, I need to add support for deleting devices, but I cannot figure out how I would change the parameter definition.

I was thinking of using a [switch] to determine if the user wants to add or delete a property. If the user included the -Add switch when running the script, then I will require both $PropertyNames and $PropertyValues. If they include -Delete, the I will only require $PropertyName.

What would be the best way to achieve this? Would it be better to have a parameter called "Operation" that will take "Add" or "Delete" and then base the PropertyName/Values requirement on the value of $Operation?

Thanks. The code snippet is below:

```
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName=’Default’)]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’Default’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’NameFilter’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’IPFilter’)]
        [string]$AccessId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’Default’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’NameFilter’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’IPFilter’)]
        [string]$AccessKey,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’Default’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’NameFilter’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’IPFilter’)]
        [string]$AccountName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName=’Default’)]
        [int]$DeviceId,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName=’NameFilter’)]
        [string]$DeviceDisplayName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName=’IPFilter’)]
        [string]$DeviceName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’Default’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’NameFilter’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’IPFilter’)]
        [string[]]$PropertyNames,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’Default’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’NameFilter’)]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName=’IPFilter’)]
        [string[]]$PropertyValues,
        [switch]$WriteLog,
        [string]$LogPath
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a parameter is available in all parameter sets you don't need to add a separate `[Parameter()]` attribute for each one unless they require unique properties in different sets.

The switches can be used the way you want, the thing is you need to sort of multiplex it with all of the other sets. So if each of the 3 sets you have now could be used in either an `-Add` or `-Remove` scenario, then you will be going to 6 different parameter sets now.

```
function Invoke-Thing {
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='DefaultAdd')]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$AccessId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$AccessKey,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]$AccountName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='DefaultAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='DefaultRemove')]
        [int]$DeviceId,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='NameFilterAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='NameFilterRemove')]
        [string]$DeviceDisplayName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='IPFilterAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ParameterSetName='IPFilterRemove')]
        [string]$DeviceName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string[]]$PropertyNames,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='DefaultAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='NameFilterAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='IPFilterAdd')]
        [string[]]$PropertyValues,

        [switch]$WriteLog,
        [string]$LogPath ,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='DefaultAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='NameFilterAdd')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='IPFilterAdd')]
        [switch]$Add ,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='DefaultRemove')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='NameFilterRemove')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, ParameterSetName='IPFilterRemove')]
        [switch]$Remove
    )

}
```

And here's the `Get-Help` output showing the sets:

```
NAME
    Invoke-Thing

SYNTAX
    Invoke-Thing -AccessId <string> -AccessKey <string> -AccountName <string> -DeviceId <int> -PropertyNames <string[]> -PropertyValues <string[]> -Add [-WriteLog] [-LogPath <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Invoke-Thing -AccessId <string> -AccessKey <string> -AccountName <string> -DeviceId <int> -PropertyNames <string[]> -Remove [-WriteLog] [-LogPath <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Invoke-Thing -AccessId <string> -AccessKey <string> -AccountName <string> -DeviceDisplayName <string> -PropertyNames <string[]> -Remove [-WriteLog] [-LogPath <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Invoke-Thing -AccessId <string> -AccessKey <string> -AccountName <string> -DeviceDisplayName <string> -PropertyNames <string[]> -PropertyValues <string[]> -Add [-WriteLog] [-LogPath <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Invoke-Thing -AccessId <string> -AccessKey <string> -AccountName <string> -DeviceName <string> -PropertyNames <string[]> -Remove [-WriteLog] [-LogPath <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]

    Invoke-Thing -AccessId <string> -AccessKey <string> -AccountName <string> -DeviceName <string> -PropertyNames <string[]> -PropertyValues <string[]> -Add [-WriteLog] [-LogPath <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]


ALIASES
    None


REMARKS
    None
```